# How to expand the div height according to content?

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to make notes webpage like google keep.[I tried setting height to auto but it still doesn't works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7fRx.png)

i want the div container to expand height with the increase in the content.[this is the result when i set height to auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVZ7N.png)

[i want to get result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuQLN.png)

```
.note {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #82589F;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    height: fit-content;
    margin: 16px;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 2rem;
  }
  .note h1 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
  }
  .note p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3rem;
    font-size: 20px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: #A3A3A3;
  }


  .note button {
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    height: 0px;
    bottom: 1rem;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
  }
```

Comment: your height is not set to `auto` but to `fit-content` as you overwrite it.

Comment: Remove `position: absolute` from the `p` tag. Absolute should be used rarely. Using absolute makes parent of that element think that there is nothing inside of it

Comment: CSS without the HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please present a proper [mre] of your issue when asking questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the height property

> The height CSS property specifies the height of an element. By default, the property defines the height of the content area.

Read more about the height property [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)

I did a litle [example](https://playcode.io/1525701)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="note">
<h1>Note Title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor purus sed aliquet ultrices. Aliquam finibus congue lobortis. Duis consectetur mi sed lectus euismod, a congue ligula tincidunt.</p>
<button>Button</button>
</div>
 <div class="sidebar">
<h2>Sidebar Title</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor purus sed aliquet ultrices. Aliquam finibus congue lobortis. Duis consectetur mi sed lectus euismod, a congue ligula tincidunt.</p>
</div>
</div>

<style>
  .container {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: grey;
padding: 0 20px; /* Add horizontal padding for left and right spacing */
gap: 20px; /* Add a gap between the boxes */
height: 100vh;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.note {
  display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: white;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
color: black;
text-align: center;
max-width: 300px; /* Adjust the width as desired */
 }
  .sidebar {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: white;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
color: black;
text-align: center;
max-width: 300px; /* Adjust the width as desired */
}
</style>
```